# File switcher window in IntelliJ IDEA 13 needs ENTER hit to show a file (gnome related?)

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, gnome-3

I was using IntelliJ IDEA 12 for a while and I literally love file switcher panel for quick skipping between opened classes, files, etc.

Default behaviour: CTRL+TAB invoked the panel, holding CTRL + TAB, TAB, TAB... for selecting desired class/file, **release CTRL --> panel disappeared**, the main editor window switched to selected class/file.

Then... I pressed something "weird"? Don't remember, emotional intensive coding...

Current, very annoying behaviour: The file switcher does not disappear after CTRL release now. **I need to press ENTER** to close file switcher and to be switched into the class in editor.

How can I set up the switcher to react and selecting files just after CTRL release again?

I wasn't able to find configuration for file switcher panel in ~/.IntelliJIdea13/* so far. Any idea what can be a possible reason? Maybe something in Gnome v3.2.1?

Thank you.

Edit: just found out, I can very quickly jump between opened class/file tabs using ALT+LEFT, ALT+RIGHT while "writing code". It's even more ergonomic!

Edit2: It looks like it is not IDE related. I've tried to start IDEA with absolutely clear config and the switcher is still not working properly. Chmmmm...

Comment: With some light of "edit2": If anyone feel that this question should be closed/improved/edited, feel free to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is really strange, I tried to search for some settings related to this but couln't find anything (using Ctrl + Shift + A which is cool shortcut).

The only thing I can recommend is to remove (or backup) your ~/.IntelliJIdea13 config folder and see if it works with clean config and you can rule out any weird gnome/whatever behaviour.

If it works with clean you can do diff on the config files..

Comment: That is great idea and I've tried it out immediately. The same problem even with totally clean config => this is not IDE related! Pffff... (thanks, I'm so focused on my project that idea of diff configs didn't come to my mind)